# How to fix first column in table while scrolling horizontally not vertically in AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am showing data in table where we are showing some records, I want to fix first column position in horizontal scrolling but want to scroll it if scrolling is vertical.

```
   <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>
                SRD_NAME
            </th>
            <th>
                CREATED_BY_USER_ID
            </th>
            <th>
                SRD_NAME_ID
            </th>
            <th>
                CREATED_TS
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="testdata in testdatas1 | filter:searchText| limitTo: myLimit">
            <td >
                {{testdata.sRD_NAME}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{testdata.cREATED_BY_USER_ID}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{testdata.sRD_NAME_ID}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{testdata.cREATED_TS}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I've ever seen, horizontal scrolling is not well-supported by browsers (nor typically a great user experience). A `thead` allows you to address and then stick the header rows of tables when they scroll, but they group rows, not columns.

Comment: Hi Palpaim, actually i am looking for horizontal scrolling for 2,3,4....... column, but want to keep my fist column position fixed. As column freeze in MS EXCEL.